# How to access page controls from user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Is there a way to access page controls from user control . I have some controls in my page and i want to access these controls from the user control .

Comment: Actually you don't - really you don't... I accept that there are reasons why you might want to (been there, done that) but fundamentally this is an anti-pattern - the user control should work in isolation, if its needs data you need to pass this in if it needs to affect stuff around it then it should raise events. You also have a better chance of ending up with something that can be tested in isolation. There are very few absolutes, so your use case may be entirely justified... but I'd want to take a long hard look to make sure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
YourControlType ltMetaTags = null;
Control ctl = this.Parent;
while (true)
{
    ltMetaTags = (ControlType)ctl.FindControl("ControlName");
    if (ltMetaTags == null)
    {
        ctl = ctl.Parent;
        if(ctl.Parent == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Example

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal ltMetaTags = null;
Control ctl = this.Parent;
while (true)
{
    ltMetaTags = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal)ctl.FindControl("ltMetaTags");
    if (ltMetaTags == null)
    {
        if(ctl.Parent == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ctl = ctl.Parent;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

There are actually several ways to accomplish this:

Create a public property in your user control

```
public Button PageButton { get; set; }
```

Then assign it in the page's OnInit or OnLoad method

```
myUserControl.PageButton = myPageButton;
```

You can make the control public and unbox Page:

```
public Button PageButton { get { return this.myPageButton; } }
```

In the user control:

```
MyPage myPage = (MyPage)this.Page;
myPage.PageButton.Text = "Hello";
```

The slowest, but easiest way would be to use FindControl:

```
this.Page.FindControl("myPageButton");
```

Comment: Get `null refernce exception`

`((Label)this.Page.FindControl("mylabel")).ID;`

Comment: I call this in the page load of my user control

Comment: @just_name - You'll have to post the code for me to troubleshoot it, but what you have should work IF the control "myLabel" does exist on the page and the user control has been added to the page as well.

Comment: @just_name - also note that "myLabel" must be a server-side control, not "<label id='myLabel' />"

Comment: when i write `this.Page.Controls[0]` i get `ASP.frm_masterPage`

Comment: @just_name - Start a new question or edit this one and include your source code.

Comment: the user control created in runtime like this
`MyBaseControl ctrl = (MyBaseControl)LoadControl("UserControls/" + page_new_name);pnl_PageNew_UC.Controls.Add(ctrl); `

Comment: Searching for a control on page is no automatic guarantee to find what you're searching for. FindControl() is a method that will only search in the current Child-collection. You need to do a recursive search if you don't know exactly where in the tree to start searching http://sharpertutorials.com/recursive-findcontrol/

Comment: @PauliØsterø - this would be helpful if the OP asked "How do I recursively search for a control in another control", but good to know just in case the developer forgot where he stuck his control.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Parent.FindControl("hdnValue")
```

Comment: Parent might be another user control.  Better to use this.Page.

Comment: @ChrisGessler searching for a control on page is no automatic guarantee to find what you're searching for. Page is a Control, just like UserControl is a Control, and FindControl() is a method that will only search in the current Child-collection. You need to do a recursive search if you don't know exactly where in the tree to start searching http://sharpertutorials.com/recursive-findcontrol/

Answer (score 1):

**its work for me :**

I declare Label in My `.aspx` page

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblpage" runat="server" Text="this is my page"></asp:Label>
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlUC" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

In `.aspx.cs` I have add UserControl through `Panel`

```
   UserControl objControl = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/ts1.ascx");
   pnlUC.Controls.Add(objControl);
```

and access from in `.ascx` UserControl like this :

```
 Page page = this.Page;
 Label lbl = page.FindControl("lblpage") as Label;
 string textval = lbl.Text;
```

Comment: the user control created in runtime like this

Comment: `MyBaseControl ctrl = (MyBaseControl)LoadControl("UserControls/" + page_new_name);pnl_PageNew_UC.Controls.Add(ctrl);`
`

Comment: @just_name. i add usercontrol via panel than able to access label value with this code.Hops to try this.