# Set data-atribute to control at ascx page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp-classic

I have control such as:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="IMG_id" ClientIDMode="Static" data-test ='<%=Field %>' />
```

And codebehind such as:

```
namespace Namespace
{
  public partial class ViewPage : Base
  {
    public string Field = "field test value";
  }
}
```

But it doesnt work. 
How is it possible to set this attribute at ascx page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to: Set HTML Attributes for Controls in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Set:

```
IMG_id.Attributes.Add("data-test", "whatever");
```

Get:

```
string att = IMG_id.Attributes["data-test"].ToString();
```

Comment: Its ok. But i need do it at ascx

Comment: @PashaPasha where is the image control?

Comment: directly in user control. No repeters or others.

Comment: @PashaPasha if you have the image control in the usercontrol you can accessc it how I says otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053541/how-to-access-page-controls-from-user-control#answer-10053659

Comment: thanks, but is it possible to use some analog of Eval or something?

Comment: @PashaPasha Eval is for databinding controls and <%=%> is not for aspnet controls. if you want to use <%=%> you should use an html img tag