# How to access control in user control file from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a user control which has one grid control. I used user control in a aspx page twice. Now my question is, Will it create two grid controls with different ID's? If yes, how can I access those two grid controls ?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053541/how-to-access-page-controls-from-user-control

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect, if you place the UserControl on the page twice, it will create two instances with separate Ids. It is basically the same as placing two TextBoxes on the page as they also share the same class (TextBox), but are created as separate instances with separate ids (TextBox1, TextBox2 for example).

You can access the properties or methods that are provided by a UserControl in the CodeBehind file as you'd access properties or methods of another control type. If you want to access the grids, you'd have to introduce a property on the UserControl that makes the grid accessible from the parent page:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Grid As GridView 
    Get
        Return grid
    End Get
End Property
```

In the parent page, you can then add code similar to this (for the sake of an example, I hide the grid from the parent page):

```
userCtrl1.Grid.Visible = False
userCtrl2.Grid.Visible = False
```

However, in terms of encapsulation, it would be cleaner if the page would not know which controls are placed on a UserControl. This allows you to change the UserControl afterwards without breaking the page. In order to do so, instead of publishing the Grid, you'd add the required properties and methods to the UserControl that the parent page uses to interact with the UserControl. The grid should only be accessed by the properties and methods internally:

### User Control:

```
Public Property ShowDetailData As Boolean
    Get
        Return grid.Visible
    End Get
    Set
        grid.Visible = value
    End Set
End Property
```

### Page:

```
userCtrl1.Grid.ShowDetailData = False
userCtrl2.Grid.ShowDetailData = False
```

In this example, if you decide that a Repeater is better suited for displaying the data, you can change this without breaking the page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have one more doubt.